# Cannot update property in singleton class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, singleton

I have a singleton class which has been declared like so:

```
+(instancetype)mySharedClass
{
    static BBDataStore *sharedBBDataStore = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedBBDataStore = [[self alloc]initWithDataExpiry:DATA_EXPIRY_TIME];
    });
    return sharedBBDataStore;
}

-(instancetype)initWithDataExpiry: (int) dataExpiry
{
    if (self = [super initWithDataExpiry:dataExpiry])
        {

        self.categoryWebServicePool = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.userProfileWebServicePool = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        }
    return self;
}
```

In this class, I have a public property declared as so:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int countryId;
```

Now when I set this property from another class like so:

```
[[BBDataStore sharedDataStore]setCountryId:1];
```

My custom setter run inside the singleton class:

```
-(void)setCountryId:(int)countryId
{
    switch (countryId)
    {
        case RE_INDEX:
            self.serverString = RE_SERVER_STRING;
            self.authId = BB_AUTH_SA_ID;

        break;
        case KE_INDEX:
           self.serverString = KE_SERVER_STRING;
           self.authId = BB_AUTH_KENYA_ID;

        break;
    }

}
```

However self.countryId always remains 0 and never changes its value. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom setter method doesn't actually change the value of the underlying ivar. This should work.

```
-(void)setCountryId:(int)countryId
{
    _countryId = countryId;
    switch (countryId)
    {
        case RE_INDEX:
            self.serverString = RE_SERVER_STRING;
            self.authId = BB_AUTH_SA_ID;

        break;
        case KE_INDEX:
           self.serverString = KE_SERVER_STRING;
           self.authId = BB_AUTH_KENYA_ID;

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank you so much. I just assumed the setter sets the property. Didn;t know I had to actually set the ivar directly. Ooops.

Comment: No worries.  Alternative you can use key value observing (KVO) on the property of interest so that you don't have to deal with that (or with side-effects in the setter.)

Comment: Still new to this iOS game. So will read up on KVO and see if it fits better for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with this line :

```
[[BBDataStore sharedDataStore]setCountryId:1];
```

You should use like :

```
[[BBDataStore mySharedClass] setCountryId:1];
```

You never directly access the singleton object

Also you didn't set the `countryId` property in your custom setter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update countryId. Calling `_countryId = countryId` in the setter should do the trick

Comment: This worked. Can't believe I actually missed that. Still new to iOS dev. Thank you